# Widechar sorting and loading from file

Tags: c, setlocale, widechar

I'm currently trying to solve the problem when I need to load rows from the file and then sort them in the right order.

If I manually assign lettes to the array of wint_t and then sort them, everything from just fine with any encoding http://pastebin.com/85eycH15.

But if I read the very same letters from file and then try to sort them it works just with one encoding (cs_CZ.utf8) and with the rest of them it doesn't read the letters properly or or just skip them http://pastebin.com/3C8r9W5T.

I highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Which encoding does the file use? Note: I would advice against this kind of sorting. I.e. sorting `ÆØÅ` = `{198, 216, 197}`, will not give a correct sorting for [Danish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the only encoding with which you get your expected result is the one used for your data file.  Re-encode the data file in another encoding, you'll get your expected result for the new encoding and not others.

Comment: APProgrammer: thanks, I've changed encoding of the file I want to sort and now there are just slight indifferencies at the beggining of the alphabet, but I'll handle it. @Mats: In the keyList I'm not using directly the letter from czech alphabet, but instead of it \uXXXX from Unicode table.
EDIT: On the other hand, is it possible to check, if the encoding of the opened file goes hand by hand with encoding set by the setlocale? Or eventually set the encoding of the file manually?

Comment: There are several ways to guess, all sometimes guess wrong.  It is obviously better if you can reduce the choice beforehand (for instance if you know it is ASCII, ISO-8859-2 or UTF-8, you can guess right). Search for similar questions in the archive.